# ¿Cómo devolver con PHP imágenes a un src?

Tags: php, html, imagen

En un archivo PHP alojado en un host virtual tengo un documento llamado `example.php`.

En este documento hay elementos `DIV` que contienen elementos `IMG` con `src` a un archivo llamado `imagen.php` pasándole parámetros. Pero el script lo tengo vacío porque no sé qué código debe contener para devolver bien las rutas de las imágenes.

El código de `example.php` ya estaba escrito por otra persona y no puedo cambiarlo, aparte son muchas imágenes, y es esto en lo que necesito ayuda.

Así esta escrito el código en `example.php`:

```
<div>
    <img src="imagenes/imagen.php?f=imagenes&amp;folder=foods&amp;type=salads&amp;desc=green&amp;dim=50&amp;id=23" alt="green salad 23">
</div>
```

En el mismo directorio donde esta `example.php` hay una carpeta llamada "`imagenes`" (donde también está el archivo `imagen.php`) con los subdirectorios "`foods/salads/green_50`" y ahí se encuentran todas las imágenes necesarias que puedan ser solicitadas por el documento `example.com`.

Yo intenté poner en el archivo `imagen.php` código obteniendo todos los valores de los parámetros con `$GET[]` y luego devolver con `echo` la ruta correcta pero creo que así no se hace porque no da resultado y no sé cómo hacer.

Si yo le cambio el `src` al `div` de arriba funciona todo bien, pero no puedo hacerlo en todos, son miles.

```
<div><img src="imagenes/foods/salads/green_50/23.png"></div>
```

Comment: Daniel bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Verás que he editado tu pregunta quitando los code snippets, ya que esa funcionalidad es para probar código que funcione. En tu caso no funcionará porque las rutas no son parte de este sitio, en esos casos es mejor poner el código simplemente, como está ahora. En cuanto a tu problema, no acabo de entender del todo lo que quieres, pero creo que sería más simple construir directamente las rutas de las imágenes que quieres, enlazando parámetros. Tú comentas que son muchas imágenes... pero si logras encontrar la lógica de esas muchas imágenes podrás automatizar.

Comment: Y como hago eso?

Comment: OK ahora entiendo, gracias.

Comment: Lo que quiero es saber como crear el código en el archivo "imagen.php" para que devuelva las imagenes a los SRC de los DIV.

Comment: Daniel le falta claridad a tu pregunta, por ejemplo tú dices: *... y en esta ultima se encuentran todas las imágenes necesarias que puedan ser solicitadas por el documento example.com ...*. Y yo pregunto, **¿de qué manera el documento `example.com` solicita las imágenes?**. ¿Las imágenes están, como dices, en un archivo dentro de un `div`?, ¿por qué no consideras una mejor organización de tu contenido, sin tener que depender quizá de algo complicado que alguien hizo? ¡Es que son muchas imágenes! No importa, si hay un mismo patrón, tú puedes sacarlas todas aparte, en un array , en un archivo...

Comment: ... en una base de datos, o donde quieras. Luego leer esa fuente según lo que te pida `example.com` y construir la ruta encadenando los posibles valores. No sé si me doy a entender. Te estoy dando ideas de cosas que podrías hacer, pero si tú no llegas a explicar bien la situación es imposible poder ayudarte más de ahí. Uno no tiene por qué conformarse con un trabajo que otro hizo, si tiene la libertad de implementar cosas nuevas, como una fuente de información más organizada que te ahorrará quizá horas y horas de trabajo, aunque al principio cueste extraer esos datos. Saludos.

Comment: con "esta ultima" me refiero a la carpeta "green_50" (la carpeta que contiene todas las posibles imagenes: 23.png, 24.png,etc., que pueden ser solicitadas en los SRC) la cual esta dentro de "salads" que a su vez esta dentro de "foods" que a su vez esta dentro de "imagenes".

Comment: Mira mas abajo alguien respondió pero otra persona Mariano cree que no es indispensable usar recurso GD en memoria cuando se puede volcar el contenido del archivo de imagen directamente.

Comment: Mira hasta ahora pude desde el archivo imagen.php recuperar los parametros con $GET, tambien puedo devolver una URL pero asi no funciona. Como dicen mas abajo lo que este archivo imagen.php debe devolver son las imagenes en si, aca es donde no se como hacer. Por ejemplo todos los valores de f=,,folder=,type=,desc,dim=50,id=23 los puedo obtener y formar la URL en donde se ubica el archivo solicitado, en este caso "23.png", pero no se como devolver la imagen en si. AH  ¿de qué manera el documento example.com solicita las imágenes? pues   desde los SRC  de los IMG dentro de los DIV.

Comment: ¿Cómo que devolver las imágenes en sí? Si tú tienes las imágenes ya en una carpeta, ¿por qué el código PHP tiene que devolver las imágenes en sí? ¿Devolverlas para qué? Si tú quieres mostrar las imágenes, **solamente tienes que construir una ruta válida que las muestre**, con `<img src ...>`. Creo que esto mismo es lo que te quiso decir @Mariano. Otra cosa es que necesites enviar las imágenes a otra parte (por ejemplo por correo electrónico), entonces sí necesitarías obtener las imágenes en sí. En fin, sigo sin entender.

Comment: Mira si yo cambio el códigode los divs de la primera pregunta por este: <div><img src="imagenes/foods/salads/green_50/23.png"></div> funciona todo bien, pero no puedo cambiarlos a mano.

Comment: aclaro, el documento example.php (no .com) esta en un servidor virtual de wampserver en mi pc. Este tiene miles de DIVs <div>
<img src="imagenes/imagen.php?f=imagenes&amp;folder=foods&amp;type=salads&amp;desc=green&amp;dim=50&amp;id=23" alt="green salad 23">
</div>   (cambiando los id=24, 25,etc)

Comment: Lo que yo debo hacer (por lo menos creo yo) es crear el archivo imagen.php para que, tomando los parametros con $GET[] de los SRC devuelva las imagenes. Simple pero yo no sé como hacerlo completamente.

Comment: Por eso yo te decía que puedes organizar tu contenido y entonces mostrarlo de forma automática, según lo que se te pida en `example.com`. Por ejemplo: digamos que en `example.com` te piden la `green` con id `50` y el `png` con id `23`... pues tú construyes tu ruta de forma dinámica en base a esos datos que te han pedido. Algo así (suponiendo que : `$idGreen=50`  y que `$idPng=23`) construyes la `src` así de forma dinámica: `$srcImagen='<img src="imagenes/foods/salads/green_'.$idGreen.'/'.$idPng.'.png">';` Así, al hacer `echo $srcImagen;` se mostrará la imagen cuya URL hayas creado dinámica.

Comment: Mira antes que nada te agradezco mucho por tu atención y ayuda. Todas las imágenes de el documento example.php tienen SRC apuntando a imagenes/imagen.php. Pasandole 6 parametros, a estos parámetros los puedo tomar tranquilamente desde imagen.php. Con estos parametros debe construirse la ruta de la imagen y devolver la image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idealmente, en el código de `example.php`, en vez de generar el `src` como lo estás haciendo,

```
imagenes/imagen.php?f=imagenes&folder=foods&type=salads&desc=green&dim=50&id=23
```

te hubiese convenido directamente generar el `src` de la imagen. Pero como mencionaste que no podés modificarlo, vayamos al código de `imagen.php`.

En `imagen.php` no hay que imprimir la ruta, sino que hay que cargar la imagen directamente. Tené en cuenta que un archivo PHP normalmente genera un HTML, pero también puede generar cualquier otro recurso que entrega el servidor web, por ejemplo una imagen.

¿Cómo se da cuenta el navegador que recibió una imagen y no un HTML? Por el encabezado [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type), que desde el código se modifica así:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

Y luego, solamente hay que imprimir el contenido del archivo de imagen.

---

**Código:**

Primero tenemos que generar la ruta de la imagen:

```
<?php

//obtener los valores de ?f=imagenes&folder=foods&type=salads&desc=green&dim=50&id=23
// y generar la ruta foods/salads/green_50/23.png
$folder = $_REQUEST['folder'];
$type   = $_REQUEST['type'];
$desc   = $_REQUEST['desc'];
$dim    = $_REQUEST['dim'];
$id     = $_REQUEST['id'];

$imagen = $folder . '/' . $type . '/' . $desc . '_' . $dim . '/' . $id . '.png';
```

Y luego, si el archivo existe, vemos cuál es el [*MIME type*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) (es diferente para png, jpg, etc.).

```
if ( file_exists($imagen) ) {
    $mime_type = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($imagen));
    header( 'Content-Type: ' . $mime_type );
} else {
    //lo que debería hacer si no existe la imagen
    //se puede mostrar otra imagen, o devolver un 404
    http_response_code(404);
    die();
}
```

Ahora, si llegamos hasta acá, el archivo existe, ya enviamos el `Content-Type`, sólo tenemos que imprimir el contenido del archivo de la imagen:

```
readfile($imagen);
```

Comment: Mariano muchas gracias! funcionó a la perfección! Yo sabía que se podía. Un duda mas: si todas las imagenes tienen el atributo "alt" como en el ejemplo: alt="green salad 23", es necesario el "else" con lo que habrí que hacer si la imagen no existe?  Gracias de nuevo capo!

Comment: @DanielMartinez el `else`, de la forma que está escrito ahora, es la forma correcta de decirle al navegador que la imagen no existe. De lo contrario, el navegador estaría esperando una imagen y recibiría un HTML vacío.

Comment: Si por supuesto! entendiste muy bien aunque me costó  explicarlo, y me ayudaste a resolver mi duda, ahora ya se algo nuevo, gracias, saludos!

Comment: solo que en la parte donde se recuperan los valores de los parametro falta la primera f, $f = $_REQUEST['f']; y luego añadirla a $imagen = $f. '/' .$folder . '/' . $type . '/'....................

Comment: @DanielMartinez es que `imagen.php` ya se encuentra dentro de la carpeta `imagenes`... pero sí, es irrelevante si se mueve o si se genera otra ruta (la idea es la misma).

Answer (score 0):

El echo del fichero imagen.php no debe devolver la ruta de la imagen, sinó la imagen en sí, sería algo así:

imagen.php

```
<?php
    $foto = "";
    if(isset($_REQUEST["f"])) {
        $foto = $_REQUEST["f"];
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($foto); // $foto debe de ser la ruta a la imagen
        /* $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($foto); para jpg */
        /* $image = imagecreatefromgif($foto); para gif */
        header('content-type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($image);
    }
?>
```

Comment: El concepto de la respuesta está bien, pero ¿Para qué crear un recurso GD en memoria cuando se puede volcar el contenido del archivo de imagen directamente?

Comment: Es que hay en total 6 parametros, como hago para construir la URL a partir de estos? La imagagen que el archivo imagen.php debe devolver debe ser imagenes/foods/salads/green_50/23.png.  Mariano podes explicar mas, que es un recurso GD?

Comment: Entiendo, como puedo hacer para volcar ese contenido del archivo de imagen directamente?

Comment: Gracias ahora lo sé jaja perdon @Mariano

Comment: He puesto este ejemplo porque lo cogí de una parte de una web en dónde lo uso para añadir una marca de agua a las imágenes a mostrar, por eso hay un recurso GD.